# Regex specified in When clause in menu declaration fails

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

We have successfully used regex in menu/when declarations before.

This works

```
"when": "resourceExtname =~ /\\.(md|adoc)$/",
```

But this doesn't...

```
"when": "resourceExtname =~ /[.](didact)[.](md|adoc)$/",
```

I have tested it online and it seems to work as expected. https://regex101.com/r/GODM1Q/1

Any words of wisdom? I've also tried simply breaking it into two menu declarations with resourceExtName set to a complex extension:

```
"when": "resourceExtname = .didact.md",
```

And that fails also. Wondering if this is a known limit of that when filter?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `resourceExtname` is only the part after the last dot including it. You need to use `resourceFilename`:

```
"when": "resourceFilename =~ /[.](didact)[.](md|adoc)$/"
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! Glad it was something simple!